# AngularJS: How to access directive controller's $scope properties in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written an AngularJS directive for displaying tables. I used these tables on few pages and it wokred awesome, and now I have a page where I need two instances of such table. I am new to AngularJS and maybe it wasn't the best choise in the first place but so far I used the controllers scope for these tables and their directives. And when it comes to having two tables, they act like the same table when I change page for one table, the other one gets its page changed either, because they share the same scope (controller's scope).

I added scope property to the directive declaration to accept `items`(this should be common for both tables) from the controller  and within the directive's controller I declared `filteredItems`(this should not be common, each table should have its own filtered items list) property of the directive's scope.

Now my controller goes like:

```
function ($scope, sgtService, ...) {
    sgtService.getList(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });

    ...
}
```

My directive declaration is:

```
abTable: function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            items: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $filter) {
            $scope.filteredItems = [];

            $scope.$watch('items', function () {
                $scope.search();
            });

            $scope.search = function () {
                $scope.filteredItems = $filter("filter")($scope.items, $scope.searchKeywords);
            }

            ...
        }
    };
}
```

And my HTML is:

```
<div data-ab-table="" data-items="items">

    ...

    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">

        </tr>
    </tbody>

    ...

</div>
```

Directive's controller executes fine like it did before, but my problem is that for some reason in my html I can't access any properties for directive's isolated scope and I can't access these `filteredItems`. If I replace `data-ng-repeat="item in filteredItems"` with `data-ng-repeat="item in items"` it displays the content because the view controller's scope has that property `item` but it won't iterate through `filteredItems` which is property of directive's scope. And none other directive's scope properties can be accessed from there, I checked the scope id within the directive html content and it matches the id of the view's controller scope. Why within the directive's html I am dealing with view controller's scope and not with the directive's isolated scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly tweaked your example, here's the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmakarov/E5dm3/4/

Basically, it consists of the following:

- a `mytable` directive, it takes `items` array and produces a table with two rows - original numbers and odd (filtered) numbers
- a `dataProducer` service, it produces an array of 10 elements - each one calculates as index times provided multiplier.
- controller with couple of arrays, couple of multipliers and corresponding watchers.

It works like so: you click on any button, that changes corresponding multiplier, controller's watcher updates corresponding data row, directive's watcher kicks in (because the data row changes) and invokes `$scope.search()` and that modifies local scope's `filteredData` property. Two instances of this directive present on the page, and no scope clashing happens.

And if I'm not mistaken, you're trying to access properties belonged to a directive's scope from outside's HTML. That is simply won't work - just no way. If there's something calculated inside your directive and outside world needs to get access to it - move this logic to the controller.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. What I understood from those two replies is that I should always use template for directives. Actually I was going to move that code to template later, but I didn't know that it matters whether html is in a template or within the directive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access your directive's isolated scope from outside the directive like that.  Can you make your directive wrap the table HTML like this:

```
.directive('abTable', function($filter){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '=items',
      searchKeywords: '=searchKeywords' 
    },
    template: '<table><tr data-ng-repeat="item in filteredItems"><td>{{item.id}}</td><td>{{item.value}}</td></tr></table>',
    controller: function ($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.filteredItems = [];

        $scope.$watch('items', function () {
          $scope.search();
        });

        $scope.search = function () {
          $scope.filteredItems = $filter("filter")($scope.items, $scope.searchKeywords);
        }
    }
  };
```

[This example](http://jsbin.com/rucin/1/edit) shows two tables using the same items filtered differently.